# calculate weekly and monthly sales from daily sales

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have daily sales, how do I show weekly and monthly sales along with daily in a single record in oracle?  I can calculate weekly sum and monthly sum in separate tables, but I want to the results in a single data set.

Output should look like shown below.

```
Date      Week  Month   Daily_Sale    Weekly_Sale Monthly_Sale
1/1/20      1      1        $5            $5          $5
1/2/20      1      1        $5            $10         $10
1/3/20      1      1        $1            $11         $11
1/4/20      1      1        $2            $13         $13
1/5/20      1      1        $5            $18         $18
1/6/20      1      1        $1            $19         $19
1/7/20      1      1        $1            $20         $20
1/8/20      2      1        $5            $5          $25
1/8/20      2      1        $5            $10         $30
1/10/20     2      1        $1            $11         $31
1/11/20     2      1        $2            $13         $33
1/12/20     2      1        $5            $18         $38
1/13/20     2      1        $1            $19         $39
1/14/20     2      1        $1            $20         $40
```

Thank you!

Edit: Highlighting the table

Comment: Kindly mention which db you are using.

Comment: Grouping sets or a union.

Comment: I tried Select to_char(Date,'IW') Week,  Sum(Daily Sales) Weekly_Sales and Group by to_char(Date,'IW') Week Order by Week Asc. I have some other conditions applied in a where clause, but once I execute I get result of sales by week.  Then I tried to join this result set to the main table on week number expecting to see weekly_sales next to daily sales, but I get an error.  I don't have sql studio. I am coding in Alteryx so I can't see the detailed error.

Comment: You actually want running totals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have oracle compiler so I replicated the scenario in SSMS.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT T1.D1, T1.AnnualSales, T1.MonthlySales, T1.WeeklySales, T1.DailySales
 From
(SELECT [Date] As D1,
      Sum([Sales]) Over (Partition by Year(Date)) as AnnualSales,
      Sum([Sales]) Over (Partition by Month(Date)) as MonthlySales,
      Sum([Sales]) Over (Partition by Datepart(wk,Date)) as WeeklySales,
      Sum([Sales]) Over (Partition by Day(Date)) as DailySales
  FROM [dbo].[DailySales_Test]) AS T1
  Group by T1.D1, T1.AnnualSales, T1.MonthlySales, T1.WeeklySales, T1.DailySales
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want running totals. Assuming that your tables contains sales information for more than a single year you need to partition on year as well.

```
select Date, extract(week from Date) Wk, extract(year from Date) Yr,
    Daily_Sale,
    sum(Daily_Sale) over (
        partition by extract(year from Date), extract(week from Date)
        order by Date
    ) as Weekly_Sale
    sum(Daily_Sale) over (
        partition by extract(year from Date), extract(month from Date)
        order by Date
    ) as Monthly_Sale
from T
order by Date;
```

Comment: I'll try this partition argument.  I have to key in only the dimensions for which I need partition on, correct?

Comment: I think so. Not certain I understand the question.

Comment: My table has other dimensions like market number, zones, other measure like Gross Profit, etc.  So when I do a partition by I have part it on market number, zones, etc.  I am not how measures like Gross Profit will behave so I'll test that with actual numbers.  My Daily sales is not a single measure, it's a aggregate of whole much of daily transaction (with some where clauses).

Comment: `partion by` will let you compute an aggregate based on other rows that have the same attributes as the current row. If those other dimensions are relevant to defining your slices then you would add them all there.

Comment: Extract(week from...) does not work. Use TRUNC(...,'IW')

Comment: Thanks @Wernfried. I didn't have access to an Oracle server to test. My reference said those functions were available, which actually surprised me.

Comment: Yes, I notice week is a not a native function.  I tried this and I and getting correct output

Comment: Select 
Extract(Day From DATE) Day, 
DATE,
To_Char(DATE + 1, 'IW') Wk, Extract(Year From DATE) Yr, Extract(Month From DATE) Mn, 

Sum(SALES) Over (Partition By Extract(Year From DATE), Extract(Month From DATE),Extract(Day From DATE) Order By DATE) As Day_Sale, 

Sum(SALES) Over (Partition By Extract(Year From DATE), To_Char(DATE + 1, 'IW') Order By DATE) As Weekly_Sale, 

Sum(SALES) Over (Partition By Extract(Year From DATE), Extract(Month From DATE) Order By DATE) As Monthly_Sale 

From T 

Order By DATE

Comment: My sales is not like I mentioned in the example. It's sum of transactions that I had grouped by day.  So I added that part in the code and I am seeing same result for day, week and month.

Comment: Use a cte to aggregate first.

Comment: Yes. I used my aggregated table as a subquery and it works fine. Thank you shawnt00